# AVR gcc version < gcc release versions -- why?

Tags: c++, gcc, avr, atmelstudio

I noticed that gcc for AVR lags behind the main development stream of gcc. For example, gcc for AVR8 is 4.9.2 in Atmel Studio 7 and Arduino, and AVR32 is at 4.4.7 in Atmel Studio. Meanwhile, gcc 4.9.4 is the current 4.9 release, and development is pushing multiple branches 5.x, 6.x and 7.x (https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html).

**Update (November 2019):**
Atmel Studio and the Arduino toolchain are now up to gcc 5.4, which still only fully implements C++11.

---

My concern is that I may run into early implementation issues by using recently added features of the C++ language with an older compiler. Additionally, the development process of AVR support in gcc is unclear.

- Are new features of the C++ language being added to the gcc + AVR toolchain?
- Can I use them with Atmel Studio or the Arduino IDE?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking us why a company took certain decisions? Or how the GCC development works? As for the language features - the support of them is well documented on the GCC website.

Comment: Because it takes time for Atmel to update their customized GCC. It compiles to a different platform, and they have to merge sources. It takes a lot of time. Also this question is off-topic for StackOverflow due to having primarily opinion-based answers, and will eventually be closed.

Comment: You can get an up-to-date avr-gcc toolchain as an Arch Linux package, or just compile it yourself:  https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/avr-gcc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a particular version of GCC you want to use, just use it.  Build it yourself or get a pre-built, there is no reason you need to use the Atmel sandbox.

Comment: This answer is useful going forward though not quite the answer I was expecting -- actually I wasn't sure what was going to come back.

Comment: This answer is quite wrong, mainline GCC does not support AVR32 because support for it was never upstreamed...

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

gcc supports compiling for AVR when built with certain build options and passed the correct flags. gcc built with those AVR-specific build options is avr-gcc.

Both Atmel and Arduino ship with a custom build of [avr-gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) and the rest of the needed toolchain (binutils, avr-libc). Arduino is actually downstream of Atmel's toolchain, and Arduino only updates their toolchain when Atmel does.

There is a [nifty blog post](https://blog.zakkemble.net/avr-gcc-builds/) by Zak Kemble that has the recent builds for everything in the toolchain (avr-gcc, binutils, avr-libc), available for Windows (along with Make and AVRDUDE), Linux, and MacOS. Additionally, Arch Linux keeps an up-to-date build of avr-gcc [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/avr-gcc/) as a package.

For Arduino, the blog post I mentioned details how to integrate an updated build of avr-gcc into Arduino IDE and includes a build script if you want to build avr-gcc on your own. I have not used Atmel Studio and do not know if it is possible to swap out the avr-gcc build in a similar manner, but the [release notes](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/avr8-gnu-toolchain-3.6.1.1752-readme.pdf) make me think it may be possible.

### Caveats:

- One point discussed on the [gcc wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) but not discussed here is avr-libc, which appears largely inactive (no repo commits in several years). Even if gcc supports your target platform, avr-libc must support it, as well. As mentioned above, support is halted at gcc 5.x.
- Atmel warns there are known limitations with C++ on AVR, and the avr-libc FAQ [discusses it here.](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus) Basically, **if you’re hoping for the Standard Library, you’re out of luck**.

  - If you just need STL containers, [someone ported the SGI STL to AVR](https://github.com/andysworkshop/avr-stl). It's ancient, though.

### Summary:

Atmel and Arduino include avr-libc which only supports gcc through 5.x. This gives you access to C++11. You *can* swap this out for a newer build of avr-gcc, binutils, and the rest and continue to use the IDE (at least for Arduino).  If you would like to free up your choice of IDE, use AVRDUDE or arduino-cli (which uses AVRDUDE anyway) and call them from your IDE or the command line. Lastly, there is no modern, >= C++11 Standard Library implementation available for AVR, to my knowledge (and I have looked).